# How to store big elements in byte

Tags: java, arrays, types, char, byte

Here it is a substitution from `Sbox []`. I don't know how to choose the type of array `Sbox []`? Do you know, how the array `message []` could take elements from `Sbox []` and don't cut them.

```
byte [] message = new byte [64];  //message of 512 bits
Sbox [] = {0xFC, 0xEE....}; //here 256 elements, but some of them more than 127, e.g. 0xFC = 252

 for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
     message [ i ] = ( byte ) ( Sbox ( message [ i ] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want this:

```
byte[] message = new byte[64];
int[] sbox = {...};
for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    message[i] = (byte) sbox[i];
}
```

You don't lose any data when casting an `int` to `byte` if it's within the range of unsigned byte.

Comment: unsigned cannot be resolved to a type in java, isn't it? but my array Sbox[] has elements out of the range type Byte

Comment: You can store unsigned bytes in an array of `byte`s (both take 8 bits). To get the unsigned value as `int`, just do `value & 0xff`.